# Terraform init/plan/apply without internet host

Tags: linux, azure, terraform, cloud, devops

I am trying terraform init, plan and apply, this task is performing in host with no internet access, we will call host name is  host_no_internet

To achive, I have downloaded plugins from internet access host using below command,  we will call host name is host_with_internet

```
#executed in machine host_with_internet
terraform providers mirror plugins
```

Copied all downloaded files from host_with_internet to host_no_internet to directory "/home/tfuser/plugings"

performed below settings in home directory

```
cat /home/tfuser/.terraformrc

provider_installation {
  filesystem_mirror {
    path = "/home/tfuser/plugins/"
  }
}
```

plugins directory structure and files:

```
└── registry.terraform.io
    └── hashicorp
        ├── azurerm
        │   ├── 2.79.1.json
        │   ├── index.json
        │   └── terraform-provider-azurerm_2.79.1_linux_amd64.zip
        ├── local
        │   ├── 2.1.0.json
        │   ├── index.json
        │   └── terraform-provider-local_2.1.0_linux_amd64.zip
        └── tls
            ├── 3.1.0.json
            ├── index.json
            └── terraform-provider-tls_3.1.0_linux_amd64.zip
```

other useful configs

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.79.1"
    }
  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  client_id            = var.SP_CLIENT_ID
  client_secret        = var.SP_CLIENT_SECRET
  tenant_id            = var.SP_TENANT_ID
  subscription_id      = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  features {}
}

terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "xxxxxxxxxxxRG"
    storage_account_name = "xxxxxxxxxstore01"
    container_name       = "xxxxxxxxcontainer"
    key                  = "xxxxxxxdev.tfstate"
  }
}
```

terraform init is working, However terraform plan will hang, debug logs

it is still trying to reach internet

2021-10-07T23:57:27.609-0700 [ERROR] Checkpoint error: Get "https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform?arch=amd64&os=linux&signature=58c44c98-e7a2-c604-0a71-22fe60fa2d22&version=1.0.8": read tcp 1.1.1.1:33870->13.224.7.88:443: read: connection reset by peer

Not sure why, still it is contacting internet, what files i missed to dwonload, does any other settings I missed to perform?

I have disabled checkpoint_disable  as per below commet

but still get logs:

I did but still hangs at Accept-Encoding: gzip: timestamp=2021-10-08T08:06:17.636-0700
2021-10-08T08:06:17.842-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Request to https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/servicePrincipals?%24filter=appId+eq+%27xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1a4%27&api-version=1.6 completed with no response: timestamp=2021-10-08T08:06:17.842-0700
2021-10-08T08:07:17.843-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: GoAzureHelpers Request:
GET /xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/servicePrincipals?%24filter=appId+eq+%xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%27&api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.windows.net
User-Agent: Go/go1.16.7 (amd64-linux) go-autorest/v14.2.1 Azure-SDK-For-Go/v57.4.0 graphrbac/1.6

More logs:

```
2021-10-07T23:57:27.529-0700 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: built configuration for "azurerm" backend with hash value 1105663864
2021-10-07T23:57:27.529-0700 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "00000000-000000-0000000000"
2021-10-07T23:57:27.529-0700 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "00000000-000000-0000000000"
2021-10-07T23:57:27.530-0700 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: working directory was previously initialized for "azurerm" backend
2021-10-07T23:57:27.530-0700 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: using already-initialized, unchanged "azurerm" backend configuration
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [INFO]  Testing if Service Principal / Client Certificate is applicable for Authentication..
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [INFO]  Testing if Multi Tenant Service Principal / Client Secret is applicable for Authentication..
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [INFO]  Testing if Service Principal / Client Secret is applicable for Authentication..
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [INFO]  Using Service Principal / Client Secret for Authentication
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [INFO]  Getting OAuth config for endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/ with  tenant 00000-00000-00000
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: instantiated backend of type *azure.Backend
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: scanning directory .terraform/providers
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.79.1 for linux_amd64 at .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/linux_amd64
2021-10-07T23:57:27.531-0700 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local v2.1.0 for linux_amd64 at .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.1.0/linux_amd64
2021-10-07T23:57:27.532-0700 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls v3.1.0 for linux_amd64 at .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls/3.1.0/linux_amd64
2021-10-07T23:57:27.532-0700 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: including .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/linux_amd64 as a candidate package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm 2.79.1
2021-10-07T23:57:27.532-0700 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: including .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.1.0/linux_amd64 as a candidate package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local 2.1.0
2021-10-07T23:57:27.532-0700 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: including .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls/3.1.0/linux_amd64 as a candidate package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls 3.1.0
2021-10-07T23:57:27.609-0700 [ERROR] Checkpoint error: Get "https://checkpoint-api.hashicorp.com/v1/check/terraform?arch=amd64&os=linux&signature=58c44c98-e7a2-c604-0a71-22fe60fa2d22&version=1.0.8": read tcp 1.1.1.1:33870->13.224.7.88:443: read: connection reset by peer
2021-10-07T23:57:28.008-0700 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: using cached result from previous scan of .terraform/providers
2021-10-07T23:57:28.044-0700 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: using cached result from previous scan of .terraform/providers
2021-10-07T23:57:28.081-0700 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2021-10-07T23:57:28.081-0700 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/usr/local/bin"
2021-10-07T23:57:28.081-0700 [INFO]  Failed to read plugin lock file .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: open .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: no such file or directory
2021-10-07T23:57:28.081-0700 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend *azure.Backend does not support operations, so wrapping it in a local backend
2021-10-07T23:57:28.081-0700 [INFO]  backend/local: starting Plan operation
2021-10-07T23:57:28.081-0700 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state manager for workspace "default"
2021-10-07T23:57:28.081-0700 [DEBUG] Building the Blob Client from an Access Token (using user credentials)
2021-10-07T23:57:28.082-0700 [DEBUG] backend/remote-state/azure Request:
POST /00000-0000-00000-0000/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 HTTP/1.1^M
Host: login.microsoftonline.com^M
User-Agent: Go/go1.16.4 (amd64-linux) go-autorest/adal/v1.0.0^M
Content-Length: 172^M
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded^M
Accept-Encoding: gzip

removed few  secret logs..continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
Content-Length: 1450^M
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache^M
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8^M
Date: Fri, 08 Oct 2021 06:57:27 GMT^M
Expires: -1^M
P3p: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"^M
Pragma: no-cache^M

2021-10-07T23:57:28.613-0700 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state lock for workspace "default"
2021-10-07T23:57:28.613-0700 [DEBUG] Azure Backend Request:
HEAD /container/containerdev.tfstate HTTP/1.1^M
Host: ccipectedevwus2store01.blob.core.windows.net^M
User-Agent: Terraform/1.0.8^M
X-Ms-Date: Fri, 08 Oct 2021 06:57:28 GMT^M
X-Ms-Version: 2018-11-09
2021-10-07T23:57:28.615-0700 [DEBUG] Azure Backend Response for https://xxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/container/containerdev.tfstate:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^

2021-10-07T23:57:28.636-0700 [TRACE] backend/local: retrieving local state snapshot for workspace "default"
2021-10-07T23:57:28.636-0700 [TRACE] backend/local: building context for current working directory
2021-10-07T23:57:28.645-0700 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: starting
2021-10-07T23:57:28.645-0700 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: loading provider schemas
2021-10-07T23:57:28.645-0700 [TRACE] LoadSchemas: retrieving schema for provider type "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"
2021-10-07T23:57:28.645-0700 [DEBUG] created provider logger: level=trace
2021-10-07T23:57:28.645-0700 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2021-10-07T23:57:28.680-0700 [DEBUG] provider: starting plugin: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5 args=[.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5]
2021-10-07T23:57:28.680-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin started: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5 pid=8566
2021-10-07T23:57:28.680-0700 [DEBUG] provider: waiting for RPC address: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5
2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "API Management"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "API Management"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "App Configuration"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "App Configuration"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "AppService"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "AppService"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.690-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "Batch"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "Batch"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "EventHub"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "EventHub"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "Load Balancer"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "Load Balancer"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "Microsoft SQL Server / Azure SQL"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "Microsoft SQL Server / Azure SQL"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "Policy"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "Policy"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "Resources"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "Resources"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "Web"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Resources for "Web"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5: Registering Data Sources for "Advisor"..: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.691-0700


2021-10-07T23:57:28.802-0700 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: GetProviderSchema
2021-10-07T23:57:28.802-0700 [TRACE] provider.stdio: waiting for stdio data
2021-10-07T23:57:28.884-0700 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: Close
2021-10-07T23:57:28.884-0700 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2021-10-07T23:57:28.885-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5 pid=8566
2021-10-07T23:57:28.886-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
2021-10-07T23:57:28.886-0700 [TRACE] LoadSchemas: retrieving schema for provider type "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local"
2021-10-07T23:57:28.886-0700 [DEBUG] created provider logger: level=trace
2021-10-07T23:57:28.886-0700 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2021-10-07T23:57:28.920-0700 [DEBUG] provider: starting plugin: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.1.0_x5 args=[.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.1.0_x5]
2021-10-07T23:57:28.920-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin started: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.1.0_x5 pid=8575
2021-10-07T23:57:28.920-0700 [DEBUG] provider: waiting for RPC address: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.1.0_x5
2021-10-07T23:57:28.926-0700 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-local_v2.1.0_x5: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.925-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.961-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-local_v2.1.0_x5: plugin address: address=/tmp/plugin150241093 network=unix timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:28.961-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:28.961-0700 [DEBUG] provider: using plugin: version=5
2021-10-07T23:57:29.005-0700 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: GetProviderSchema
2021-10-07T23:57:29.005-0700 [TRACE] provider.stdio: waiting for stdio data
2021-10-07T23:57:29.006-0700 [TRACE] GRPCProvider: Close
2021-10-07T23:57:29.007-0700 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2021-10-07T23:57:29.007-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.1.0_x5 pid=8575
2021-10-07T23:57:29.007-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
2021-10-07T23:57:29.007-0700 [TRACE] LoadSchemas: retrieving schema for provider type "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls"
2021-10-07T23:57:29.007-0700 [DEBUG] created provider logger: level=trace
2021-10-07T23:57:29.007-0700 [INFO]  provider: configuring client automatic mTLS
2021-10-07T23:57:29.045-0700 [DEBUG] provider: starting plugin: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls/3.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-tls_v3.1.0_x5 args=[.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls/3.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-tls_v3.1.0_x5]
2021-10-07T23:57:29.045-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin started: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls/3.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-tls_v3.1.0_x5 pid=8584
2021-10-07T23:57:29.045-0700 [DEBUG] provider: waiting for RPC address: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls/3.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-tls_v3.1.0_x5
2021-10-07T23:57:29.051-0700 [INFO]  provider.terraform-provider-tls_v3.1.0_x5: configuring server automatic mTLS: timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:29.051-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:29.087-0700 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-tls_v3.1.0_x5: plugin address: network=unix address=/tmp/plugin196553658 timestamp=2021-10-07T23:57:29.087-0700
2021-10-07T23:57:29.087-0700 [DEBUG] provider: using plugin: version=5

finally
2021-10-08T00:05:00.933-0700 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2021-10-08T00:05:00.933-0700 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2021-10-08T00:05:00.933-0700 [DEBUG] provider.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing"
2021-10-08T00:05:00.934-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/tls/3.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-tls_v3.1.0_x5 pid=8631
2021-10-08T00:05:00.934-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
2021-10-08T00:05:00.935-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.1.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.1.0_x5 pid=8622
2021-10-08T00:05:00.935-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
2021-10-08T00:05:00.935-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin process exited: path=.terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.79.1/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v2.79.1_x5 pid=8640
2021-10-08T00:05:00.935-0700 [DEBUG] provider: plugin exited
```

Comment: You can disable it talking to Hashicorp's Checkpoint service by [setting the `CHECKPOINT_DISABLE` environment variable to a non empty value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/index.html#upgrade-and-security-bulletin-checks). Does your host still have access to the Azure API endpoints to be able to configure things?

Comment: i disabled, still same issue..but after settng up checkpoint, it does not contacting, same issue is continue and same code works fine with internet host

Comment: Having a local provider mirror can avoid `terraform init` from accessing the internet to install providers, but once you have the providers installed `terraform validate` is the only command you can run without _configuring_ the providers, and most providers access remote APIs during configuration in order to verify that you've provided suitable settings and credentials. Unless your configuration only uses APIs on your local network, `terraform plan` is always an online operation.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out, in my case making call to below url was blocking, I enabled active directory service endpoint to subnet it starts working.

https://graph.windows.net